# How to implement add_months in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How to implement add_months in PostgreSQL ??
Like oracle ADD_MONTHS returns the date.
Ex. **ADD_MONTHS(hire_date,1)**

Comment: `hire_date + interval '1' month`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
 hire_date + interval '1 month'
```

this will return exactly one month added to hire_date.

For More References on date and time functions in postgre [Date time function](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_months(start DATE, months INT) RETURNS DATE AS
$$
  SELECT (start + (months || ' months')::INTERVAL)::DATE
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL you can create a function to do the job

```
create or replace function ADD_MONTHS(var_dte date,cnt int) returns setof date as
$$
declare
qry text;
begin
qry = format( 'select (''%s''::date + interval ''%s'')::date',var_dte,cnt||' month') ;
RETURN QUERY
     EXECUTE qry;
end
$$
language plpgsql
```

and call this function

```
select ADD_MONTHS('2015-11-27',1)
```

Result:

```
add_months
      date
----------
2015-12-27
```

in your case

```
select hire_date
      ,ADD_MONTHS(hire_date,1)
from table_name
```